# I can't send Persian text form java Telegram bot intelij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, telegram, telegram-bot, farsi

I've made a telegram bot using Java with **rubenlagus/TelegramBots** library.
And when I'm going to send a Persian message to the user, the message gets all changed into nonsense like this :
[image]

real message : به پنل ادمین خوش آمدید

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE

Comment: The code that sends message might help figuring out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was *encoding* in java, which I soled it with this piece of code :

```
public static String stringWrapper(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String result = "";
    result = new String(str.getBytes() , "UTF-8");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but it did not solve the root of the problem.  Strings always have the same charset (UTF-16).  The original message was not created correctly.

Comment: Yes and unfortunately I couldn't find the answer for that. And the solution I found was a little buggy around some characters like ( ف )